# How do you convert C++ _tcscpy, _tcscat to Delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi, string, code-conversion

I'm converting [this code](http://blog.m-ri.de/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/TestAnonymousPipe.zip) from C++ to Delphi but I don't get the following part of the code. Can anyone explain me what the following code means; what's happening to the szBuff buffer ?

I'm pretty sure it's such kind of formatting (replacement), but I don't even know what is expected as a result and I can't find any sensible documentation of the used functions (maybe I'm just a lame :)

Can anyone help me with the translation of this code to Delphi (or direct me to proper documentation) ?

I don't like this how do you convert kind of questions by myself, so I mentioned at least function names in the question title so it might searchable to someone else in the future.

```
function TSecInfo.BuildSecurityAttributes(var SecAttrs: TSecurityAttributes): boolean;
var
  pszSidUser: PChar;
  szBuff: array [0..1024] of Char;
begin

// pszSidUser at this time contains user SID like this
// S-1-5-21-1454471165-1004336348-1606980848-5555

// TCHAR szBuff[1024]; // I'm not sure with array [0..1024] of Char;

  _tcscpy(szBuff, _T("D:"));
  _tcscat(szBuff, _T("(A;;GA;;;"));
  _tcscat(szBuff, pszSidUser);
  _tcscat(szBuff, _T(")"));
  _tcscat(szBuff, _T("(A;;GWGR;;;AN)"));
  _tcscat(szBuff, _T("(A;;GWGR;;;WD)"));

...

  _tcscat(szBuff, _T("S:(ML;;NW;;;S-1-16-0)"));

end;
```

For those who are interested in what's the whole code from the link about I can tell it should be a trick how to access network pipes for writing as an anonymous user on Windows Vista above. To the whole article follow [this link](http://blog.m-ri.de/index.php/2009/12/08/windows-integrity-control-schreibzugriff-auf-eine-named-pipe-eines-services-ueber-anonymen-zugriff-auf-vista-windows-2008-server-und-windows-7/).

Thanks for your time
Regards

Comment: Are you sure it is c++? Doesn't look like

Comment: @VJo - no; sure not; but the source code files has *.cpp extension and library linking like this `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: @VJo: The original code behind the link is C++.

Comment: In fact it originates from [this example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813414/en-us) where they are using Microsoft Visual C++

Comment: This is C++ code embedded inside a Pascal function.

Comment: `szBuff[1024]` implies there are 1024 elements. `array [0..1024]` is 1025 elements. You need `array[0..1024 - 1]`, sometimes written `array[0..1023]`.

Comment: @Andreas - yeah; it is; with a special `...` command :) Maybe I might omit the header.

Comment: @Andreas - thanks for this point; I would say there is reserve though but would you use `PChar` rather than `array of Char` ?

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly the sample code also uses "Shlemiel the Painter's) string concatenation (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_tcscpy` and `_tcscat` are `TCHAR` macro versions of C standard library functions `strcpy` and `strcat` for copying and concatenating C strings.  They evaluate to ANSI or Unicode versions depending on whether or the type of project you are targeting.  It's really C code rather than C++ code in my view.

In Delphi you would simply use string variables like this:

```
function TSecInfo.BuildSecurityAttributes(var SecAttrs: TSecurityAttributes): boolean;
var
  pszSidUser: PChar;
  Buff: string;
begin
  // pszSidUser at this time contains user SID like this
  // S-1-5-21-1454471165-1004336348-1606980848-5555

  Buff := 'D:(A;;GA;;;'+pszSidUser+')(A;;GWGR;;;AN)(A;;GWGR;;;WD)S:(ML;;NW;;;S-1-16-0)';
  SomeOtherWindowsAPICall(PChar(Buff));    
end;
```

Presumably in the C code there is a call to another Windows API function that receives an `LPCTSTR`. The C code will pass `szBuff` but you can simply pass `PChar(Buff)` as I have shown above.

The C code is using a fixed length buffer because it doesn't have available a dynamically allocated string class like Delphi's `string` or `std::string` in C++.  Fixed length buffers like this often lead to buffer overruns.  In Delphi don't use a fixed length buffer if you can avoid it.

This is a classic example of why languages with built in string handling are so much easier to work with than C.

Comment: +1 and accept. Thanks for the explanation; Yes the [ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is called after this where I'll use what you suggested.

Comment: God bless this dynamic allocation in Delphi :) The C code still looks for me like a spilled tea.

Comment: @daemon_x The C code would be a lot better if it dropped support for dual ANSI/Unicode builds, and better still if it was C++ and used `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code is using [TCHARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), basically they are a macro which makes going from unicode to non-unicode easier. `_tcscpy` is copying the parameter to `szBuff`, `_tcscat` is appending the parameter to `szBuff`. If you are familar with `strcpy` and `strcat` they do the same thing.

```
_tcscpy(szBuff, _T("D:")); //szBuff == "D:"
_tcscat(szBuff, _T("(A;;GA;;;")); //szBuff == "D:A;;GA;;;"
...
```

Comment: Thanks; so this means that the subsequent calling of [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) only concatenates all those strings together and it's used probably to the code be more readable ? Aren't there any special characters ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Also `_T("string")` will be `"string"` w/o UNICODE or will be `L"string"` with UNICODE.